# How to integrate google and facebook to API-M via Identity service at the same time?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

My environment is :

- wso2 API-M cluster and the Key manager is wso2 identity service.

What I wanna do is :

- User can login via Google or Facebook account to API-M publisher and store.

My question is :

- I know I have to create two identity provider for google and Facebook, and then create service provider for API-M publisher/store and identity providers.But I can't assign two issuer id in one ssoConfiguration in `<AM_Home>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/conf/site.json`

thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1):

In the service provider setting

I can add the two service in the local&outbound authentication configuration.